# Rename the page get error on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to rename the xaml and cs file, so I selected this file (in solution explorer) then pressed F2 and entered the new name. When I run it, it get error on this line system.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); Why I get error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to open the cs file and change the public class name on the cs file. In addition, change the x:Class= namespace.yourpagename on design view by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error.

As its name clearly indicates, that method pauses the debugger when called.